import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; - Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'
Just returned to a project after a couple of weeks and it now has 84 errors. I have made no changes.
The first seems to be for the line
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
gives a "Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'" error.
Same for my other projects as well.
Thanks
Changed the Gradle version in File/Project Structure yo 8.7 and this has gone away.
Now left with only 32 errors - all "Cannot access member because 'R' has primitive type int" (See attachment)

